# nginx rewrite location not found

Tags: nginx, rewrite

in Nginx config file, did set rewrite location like below but do not work and every time return 404 not found, what is the problem here?

```
server {   
listen 80;
server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
root /var/www/html/mydomain.com;
.
.
.
location /postfixadmin {
    root /var/www/html/postfixadmin/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    location ~ ^/postfixadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
       root /var/www/html/postfixadmin/;
       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
       fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
       fastcgi_buffers 256 4k;
       fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
       fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
       fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

    }
    location ~* ^/postfixadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
       root /var/www/html/postfixadmin/;
    }
}
location /PostfixAdmin {
   rewrite ^/* /postfixadmin last;
}
.
.
}
```

Comment: What kind of URLs are giving you 404?

Comment: when I click on url like : `http://www.mydomain.com/postfixadmin` ... I edited first post for more info

Comment: Have you checked the logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved by changing root location

correct config is :

```
server {   
listen 80;
server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
root /var/www/html/mydomain.com;
.
.
.
location /postfixadmin {
    root /var/www/html/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    location ~ ^/postfixadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
       root /var/www/html/;
       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
       fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
       fastcgi_buffers 256 4k;
       fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
       fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
       fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

    }
    location ~* ^/postfixadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
       root /var/www/html/;
    }
}
location /PostfixAdmin {
   rewrite ^/* /postfixadmin last;
}
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems in your configuration.

First, you are using `root` directive inside locations. This is most likely the reason for 404 errors.

You should change the first location block to start like this:

```
location /postfixadmin {
    alias /var/www/html/postfixadmin/;
```

Then, you should remove the `root` directive from the first inner `location` block.

First inner `location` start should be like this:

```
location ~ ^/postfixadmin/.+\.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
```

You don't need the second inner `location` block at all, since the alias is inherited from the parent `location` block.

Finally, you should change the last `location` to look like this:

```
location /PostFixAdmin {
    rewrite ^ /postfixadmin last;
}
```